# Revenue cat purchase

Tags: android, ios, revenuecat

how can we use one purchase for android and iOS.
if I am purchaseing from iOS app then how can I detect same purchase in android. like one purchase for both platform. is it possible from revenue cat.

thank you

Answer (score 0):

When you make a purchase, data is saved to the server.

You can retrieve the purchases for each user by making a request, so it doesn't depend on the platform:

[revenue cat documentation](https://docs.revenuecat.com/reference#basic)